# Why is extracting tabular data from PDF files hard?

Tags: parsing, pdf, text-extraction

I have a general question regarding extracting text, precisely tabular data, from PDF files.

How are PDF viewers able to read and display a table? And why can't we just get the necessary column information the same way?

I'm searching around this for a week now, mostly getting stuck with token coordinates and too wide table cells (such that an accurate intermediate empty table cell recognition becomes impossible) using pdftoxml.

I worked around this for my bunch of PDF files by regexp-ing the text (which was very successfull line by line if some interline distance is neglected and "pasted back together"), but that of course is just an instance solution.

This gives me a headache. A PDF viewer draws lines for cells and knows where a cell starts and ends but we can't read this out of the PDF source. How is this even possible? What do they know what we can't infer?

Comment: Try LocationTextExtractionStrategy class of iText or iTextSharp: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=279

Comment: Could you select a correct answer on this one or explain the reason why the answer you received doesn't answer your question (completely)? Just trying to clean up some of the PDF related questions I've answered over the years.

Answer (score 7):

The misconception you have is that a column is stored inside a PDF file as a column. That's simply not the case. A PDF viewer doesn't understand tables, columns, paragraphs, lines of text or words.

PDF was created as a page description language and it's really good at reproducing a page exactly the same on many different devices. Because that is its goal, it doesn't care about structure and what you're referring to is all structure.

The way text is drawn by PDF is really, really simple. The instructions on the page will be something like this:

- Set this font
- Go to this point on the page
- Render these characters.
- Go to this other point on the page
- Render some more characters.

While it's possible to also store some structure information in a PDF together with these instructions, it usually isn't done and it was implemented in the PDF format as an afterthought anyway.

When you look at the (pseudo) instructions above, it's easy to understand how tables are drawn. There will simply be instructions in the file to move to a certain position for one cell and draw the text. Then more instructions to move to another cell and draw that text.

If you want to reverse the operation and extract structured information from a PDF page, you'll have to "re-invent" the structure information. This means things like figuring out which text is on the same baseline and might thus belong to the same line. Which text is close enough together on that baseline so that it might be words or columns... Etc...

Not an easy task at all as you have figured out!

Comment: Some pdf generating products even seem to try to midlead text recognition software; I e.g. came across "tables" in which columns were separated by single space characters (which using the word spacing operator were stretched to match the gap) while the space between individual words in the same column was created by moving the text insertion position with explicit operators.

Comment: *grin* I'm not sure that's really misleading. I think in many cases the PDF specification simply is too complex for someone trying to finish a project on time. I wouldn't be surprised if they simply didn't understand what they were doing. I wrote a PDF text editor at some point (about fifteen years ago) and the algorithms you need would take things like what you say into account anyway. But there's an awful lot of guesswork and optimisation involved for sure...

Answer (score -3):

In the uncompressed pdf document, there are "stream objects" of following uncertain format ((0,0) being bottom left) in pseudo regexp form:

```
(x1 y1 m x2 y2 l [whitespace or blank or newline seperator symbol])* S (BT .* ET)*
```

where

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 are coordinates
l probably for "draw line"
m move to, "from to" or "merge"
S is the command for "draw" or the like
BT Begin Text
ET End Text
```

all commands postfix.

EDIT:

one possible Java regexp is (ref PDF32000_2008.pdf), after replacing newlines by blanks in the uncompressed pdf source:

```
((\s+\d+(\.\d+)?){2}(\s+m|\s+l|(\s+\d+(\.\d+)?){2}(\s+re|\s+y|\s+v|(\s+\d+(\.\d+)?){2}\s+c))\s+)+([SsFn]|[fBb](\*)?)
```

There are other elements like "W*" or "Q q" in the stream which seem to adjust line thickness or font properties at general. Since I was not able to find a language spec ad hoc, this is what I infer from experiments.

Using this information and the coordinates of the text tokens (between ET and BT), one can infer table cell widths, table starting end ending positions (for identifying different tables).

The problem remains uncompressing streams of any kind. With pdftk I was able to uncompress pdf files created from openoffice writer, but arbitrary pdf files have still cryptic symbols in them.

Further information:

http://www.gnupdf.org/Introduction_to_PDF

http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2011/05/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-%E2%80%93-carriage-returns-spaces-and-other-gaps/

http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/03/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-names-locations/

http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2011/05/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-%E2%80%93-pdf-xref-tables-explained/

[PDF page-stream optimizer library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150069/pdf-page-stream-optimizer-library)

http://www.gnupdf.org/Stream

Comment: While I appreciate the time you've spent on this answer, it is also incomplete and potentially misleading. If you want to know how a PDF file is laid out, go to http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html and download the Acrobat SDK. Part of that is the Adobe PDF file format specification (which is now also an ISO standard, ISO 32.000 to be specific). You'll find the full meaning of all of these pesky PDF operators and how to correctly uncompress PDF streams...

Comment: You mean to say adobe acrobat sdk includes some uncomression tool delivering readable text of stream objects content (more reliable than pdftk's "compress|uncompress" commands)? I would definitely appreciate a hint on this.

Comment: Not exactly, the SDK contains the PDF file format specification that explains how to perform the uncompression. It also explains how you can use Adobe Acrobat, for example by writing plug-ins, to do many of these tasks. If all you want to do is simply look at the file structure of a PDF file, there are a number of cool tools that can do this. There was (and maybe still is) a product called Browser from Enfocus and there is pdfToolbox from callas (I'm affiliated with this company) that lets you explore the low level structure of a PDF file (including the page streams).

Comment: You know, it's 2012: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF) exists and points to the [Reference](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference_archive.html).

Comment: This is an answer in progress. Since I'm answering myself, it is necessarily incomplete. Care posting a comprehensive answer. Don't just hang around in the comments.