# how to extract a table column data present in pdf and stored inside a variable python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pypdf, python-camelot

I have 3 tables (image pasted) **all 3 table(have same columns) look same and i want data of address column (yellow colour) of 3 tables stored inside a variable**.
[image]

Comment: What is your desired form of output?

Comment: address column data need to be stored in excel.

Comment: Can you share an example pdf? I think I can help but it would be much easier if I had something to show a solution on...

Comment: See also: [Why is extracting tabular data from PDF files hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14001973/562769)

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to handle extraction of tables from pdf. The final solution will depend primarily on individual pdf that you need to read. Some variables to think about when choosing the solution are:

- is the pdf just an image saved as pdf (rastered image of a scanned
  document)?
- what is the quality of pdf?
- is there any noise in the pdf
  files (e.g. spots caused by a printer) you need to get rid of?
- is the table in pdf skewed?
- how many pages has a pdf?
- how many pages a table spans across?
- how many documents do you need to scan?

There are many solutions to extract tables from pdf ranging from table-specialized OCR services to python utility libraries to help you build your own extraction program.

An example of a powerful tool to convert data from tables from pdf to excel is [Camelot](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/), which you have included in your question's tags. It abstracts a lot of complexity involved in the task at hand. You just [install](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install.html#install) it
and access it for example like that:

```
import camelot
file = 'https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/working-examples/pdf-table/table.pdf'
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file)
tables[0].to_excel('table.xlsx')
```

As I mentioned, the devil lies in the individual characteristics of a table and a pdf file.