# How can I extract text from a specific column in a table in PDF using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction

I have tried text/table extraction but I cannot isolate the specific column.Any suggestions. The table looks like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

How would i go about only extracting column B?

Thanks in advance for any help!

I was recommended to use the grid system on a PDF to identify the x coordinates of the edges of the column but this did not work.

Comment: does this answer your question?[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71138716/how-to-extract-a-table-column-data-present-in-pdf-and-stored-inside-a-variable-p)

Comment: See also: [Why is extracting tabular data from PDF files hard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14001973/562769)

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the Poppler utilities often used and found as part of Python Utilities to use direct (via os shell) to extract an Area/Region Of Interest (ROI). The following assumes Windows but for Linux/Mac you have similar bash scripting.

That will be saved with the same name as .pdf in a .txt file, or as here using `-` sent direct to console,

```
pdftotext -nopgbrk -layout -x 320 -W 50 -y 190 -H 70 specific-column.pdf -
```

or redirect multiple ROI outputs straight into a named file, in desired order.

[image]

Cursor position for unknown source is via reader measurement in "Points" for a known set of files it will be best to save the commands in a list as "Profiles" and use the profiles when looping through a folder of filenames.

If you need to do something like extract CSV for import to eXcel, you can dump full (or partial) width as text, then be more selective about gathers. so B,2,4 could be just `%i` >>lines.txt if the wider heading was an issue with the shorter cell lines.

[image]